# Module not found - “xxx module not found” - Lua lang

Tags: module, lua, require

**What to do to be able to use this module?**

File: Player.lua, my module

```lua
     local Player = {}
     local function funcPlayer()

        local player = {}
        local self = {name="", points = 0}

        local setPoints = function(newPoints)
          self.points = newPoints
        end

        local getPoints = function ()
          return self.points
        end

        local setName = function(newName)
          self.name = newName
        end

        local getName = function()
          return self.name
        end

        local f__tostring = function()
          return "(" .. self.name .. ", " .. self.points .. ")"
        end

        setmetatable(player, {
          __tostring = f__tostring
        })

        player.getPoints = getPoints
        player.setPoints = setPoints
        player.getName = getName
        player.setName = setName

        return player
    end

    Player = funcPlayer()
    return Player
```

File requesting the module: Players.lua

```
  local tabPlyer = require("Player")
```

Error message:

```
[Running] lua "c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games\Players.lua"
lua: c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games\Players.lua:1: module 'Player' not found:
    no field package.preload['Player']
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\lua\Player.lua'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\lua\Player\init.lua'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player.lua'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player\init.lua'
    no file '.\Player.lua'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player.dll'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\Player.dll'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player52.dll'
    no file '.\Player52.dll'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games\Players.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

**What to do to be able to use this module?**

*Important notes*

I am using VSCode.

PATH variable: ...; C: \ Users \ tct9 \ Documents \ Lua

Variable LUA_PATH: C: \ Users \ tct9 \ Documents \ Lua

Moon Path: C: \ Users \ tct9 \ Documents \ Lua

Script path: C: \ Users \ tct9 \ Documents \ Lua \ ScriptLua \ Games

Comment: Where is Player.lua saved?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456439/módulo-não-localizado-module-xxx-not-found-lua-lang

Comment: I made it. I followed the chapter in the book Programming in Lua 4th edition, and the error is the same.

Comment: You can also use `dofile"Player.lua"` instead of `require`
 if `Player.lua` is in the same folder as `Players.lua`.

Comment: I used dofile, but the error continues. "Cannot open Player: No such file or directory".

Answer (score 3):

> [Running] lua
>   "c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games\Players.lua" lua:
>   c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games\Players.lua:1: module
>   'Player' not found:
>       no field package.preload['Player']
>       no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\lua\Player.lua'
>       no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\lua\Player\init.lua'
>       no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player.lua'
>       no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player\init.lua'
>       no file '.\Player.lua'
>       no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player.dll'
>       no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\loadall.dll'
>       no file '.\Player.dll'
>       no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player52.dll'
>       no file '.\Player52.dll'

is the list of files Lua tries to find. If your Player.lua is not one of them you have to make sure that the file is either in one of the listed paths or that you add the path containting your file to `package.path` prior to requiring it.

Either manually from your script or by adding it to `LUA_PATH`

Comment: I changed the files to a folder "C: \ Users \ tct9 \ Documents \ Lua" and still the error continues.

Answer (score 0):

I made:

```
print (package.path)
```

And I found "C:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\?. lua"

And then I added to package.path:

```
package.path = package.path .. "; C:\\Users\\tct9\\Documents\\Lua\\ScriptLua
\\Games\\?. lua"
```

After that the module worked correctly!

Comment: ; C:\\Users\\tct9\\Documents\\Lua\\ScriptLua
\\Games\\?.lua" no space

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is to add his folder name before the module name, because the retrieval directory is in his upper directory。
like this:

```
local tabPlyer = require("FolderName.Player")
```